# Changing button background image based upon Binding

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, binding

I'm trying to get the background image from the button to change based upon a value in the MVVM linked object.

The default style for the button is image1,

when the object has been processed successful, the property is set to "Success" and the button image should change to image2

when however the object hasn't been processed succesful, the property is set to "Error: " and the button image should change to image3

I've tried binding to a string representing the location of the file ( the same string entered directly on the ImageBrush property ImageSource in the Button.Background tag.

also returning an Uri to that file is isn't working

trying to use Setter tag with triggers, the XAML breaks when using

and trying to create an BitmapImage from it with an additional property within the object isn't working either.

this is the only thing left in the app. Does somebody has some suggestions

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution for now. by removing the background from the button, and adding the following to the content:

```
      <Button.Content>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Background}" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="400" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,-130,0,0" Height="30" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
                 Foreground="White" FontFamily="/Assets/futura-md.ttf#Futura Md BT"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </Button.Content>
```

having the Background defined as following:

```
    public BitmapImage Background
    {
        get
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format( "/Assets/knop_{0}.png",buttoncolor), UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

    public string ButtonImage 
    { 
        get { return buttonimage; } 
        set 
        { 
           buttonimage = value; 
           RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonImage"); 
           RaisePropertyChanged("Background"); 
        }
    }
```

Now the button 'background' will be changed when the value of ButtonImage is changed.

It's not completely what I hoped for, but it's working.